# TFS-Workitem

Tags: tfs

I have a requirement and I am not able to figure out the solution. Any kind of help is appreciated.

We have customised the process model.

Issue.

I have FactTable say Release, Release has Project, projects would internally have different states, development-production-QA. what i need to do is generate a query that would get me all the defects that are open for a particular project, for a selected stage and selected release.

Is this possible?
Can we write sub query in TFS?

I would appreciate any kind of help provided.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do it, I would make itrations for: development, production, and QA.

Then iterations shows everywhere from the simple query to the TFS Warehouse!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider Release as team Project Collection, then Project as team Project. For development-production-QA stages you can either use Area or create a custom work item field "Stage" with reportable attribute as "dimension".

Now you can use wither TFS_Analysis i.e. Cube or TFS_Warehouse to get your data.